# How cut latex acronym chain in R dataframe

Tags: r, regex, string, latex

I have a latex file with my acronym definitions like :

```
\newacronym{AEP}{AEP}{Alimentation en Eau Potable}
\newacronym{AERMC}{AERMC}{Agence de l'Eau Rhône Méditerranée et Corse}
\newacronym[longplural=Cotes d'Abondance Numériques]{CAN}{CAN}{Cote d'Abondance Numérique}
```

My aim is to have a data frame with two columns like :

```
AEP     Alimentation en Eau Potable
AERMC   Agence de l'Eau Rhône Méditerranée et Corse
CAN     Cote d'Abondance Numérique
```

I think it's possible with regex or strsplit formula, but I can't establish it, with lot of problems with `{`

```
acronymes <- read_lines("acronymes.tex")
acronymes <- as.tbl(as.data.frame(acronymes))
acronymes %>% 
    rename(Complet = acronymes) %>% 
    filter(!grepl("^%.*", Complet)) # Because I have non used lines
acronymes$ABR <- sub("}.*","", acronymes$Complet)
```

Have you ideas or explicite manual for regex formulas ? Thank you

Comment: Well, see https://regex101.com/r/r3i5iX/1.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Nice discover of this tool, thank you for demonstration, it allows to make try to find good formula !

Comment: Note that regex101 does not support TRE, it only supports PCRE (and JS/Python, but these are not relevant for you), so you can safely test those patterns you use with `perl=TRUE` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but this works. You need to escape the braces with a double backslash:

```
a <- readLines("acronymes.tex")
acronyms <- gsub(".*\\}\\{(.*)\\}\\{.*", "\\1", a)
descriptions <- gsub(".*\\}\\{(.*)\\}$", "\\1", a)
data.frame(acronyms, descriptions)
```